# I want to put my two states input data into a table in react

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, reactjs

[image]

I want to put the input data into a table rows.
But my data is going on different lines with different tags. I have only made one tag in my imported component.

**This is the Main Component**

```
 import './App.css';
    import { useState } from 'react'
    import Data from './Data';
    
    function Component() {
    
        const [IdData, setIdData] = useState()
        const [Input, setInput] = useState()
        const [Items, setItems] = useState([])
    
        const addData = () => {
            setItems((newData) => {
                return [...newData, IdData, Input]
            })
           
            setInput("");
            setIdData("");
        }
    
        const idChange = (e) => {
            setIdData(e.target.value)
        }
        const inputChange = (e) => {
            setInput(e.target.value)
        }
    
      return (
        <>
          <div className="main">
    
          <div className="center">
              <br />
              <h2>Table Layout</h2>
            <div className="inner">
                <input className="id" type="number" autoFocus onChange={idChange} value={IdData} placeholder='ID' />
                <input type="text" placeholder='Name' onChange={inputChange} value={Input}/>
                <i className='fa fa-check' onClick={addData}></i>
            </div>
    
    
    
    
                {
                    Items.map((todoItems, index) => {
                        return <Data data={todoItems}key={index} />
    
                     
                    })
                }
                
            
          </div>
    
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }

export default Component;
```

I want to put the input data into a table rows.
But my data is going on different lines with different tags. I have only made one tag in my imported component.
**This is the imported component**

```
import React from 'react'
// import './App.css'

function Data(props) {
    return (
        <>
        <table>

            <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <tbody>
                
                <td>{props.data}</td>
            </tbody>
            </tr>
        </table>

            
                    {/* <td><i className='fa fa-times'></i></td> */}
        </>
    )
}

export default Data
```

I want to put the input data into a table rows.
But my data is going on different lines with different tags. I have only made one tag in my imported component.

**This is the CSS File**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=The+Nautigal:wght@700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope&family=The+Nautigal:wght@700&display=swap');

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #5f2c82, #49a09d);
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
p {
  display: inline;
}

.center  h2 {
  font-family: 'The Nautigal', cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.center {
  /* display: flex; */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: white;
  width: 40%;
  height: 80%;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.inner {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 30px 0 0 40px;  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: left;
}

.data {
  /* width: 20%; */
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
  display: flex; 
  /* flex-direction: row; */
  /* justify-self: stretch; */
  margin: 10px 39px 0 39px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: rgb(216, 216, 216);
  /* border-radius: 10px; */
  padding: 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
  /* width: 100%;  */
}
.inline {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.data:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 42px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #5f2c82, #49a09d);
  width: 5px;
}

.data:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #5f2c82, #49a09d);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.inner input {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.inner .id {
  width: 10%;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.fa-check {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #5f2c82, #49a09d);
  opacity: 0.7;
  
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 9%;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.fa-check:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: You're creating a new table for each item. Pass your data into the `Data` component and _then_ iterate over it, creating a new line representing the number of cells.

Comment: I have also tried that. But it just takes a new line for each item.

Comment: Sorry, I meant for each line create the number of cells from the items. You may have to rethink your state structure though. I'd suggest an array of objects where each object contains an id and a name. When you add new information a new object gets added to the state array, and it's the array that gets passed to `Data`. You can then iterate over each object and create a row from its properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try changing `setITems` as:

```
setItems((newData) => {
    return [...newData].concat([[IdData, Input]]);
});
```

Comment: Ashish, I'm disturbing you again. But how should we give space between them through CSS. I have tried many things to split them apart but as they are in one parent item and we can't give it any children of prop because in that case the value duplicates itself.

Comment: yes, because you are trying to do in single <td>. Try looping your <td> tag

`<tr>{props.data.length && props.data.map((e) => <td>{e}</td>)}</tr>`

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem. You're still generating a new table per item/row. @UsmanKhan

Comment: Correct, Even i suggest to use <th> only once, after you have data > 0, inside your Items.map.
Data component should only return row per data

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would approach it. Have two states: one to maintain the dataset (an array of objects), the other to maintain the current state of the form (an object).

When the inputs change a handler is called to update the form state, and when the button is clicked the current state of the form is added to the dataset array.

`<Table>` accepts the data state so when that changes the table changes.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  // Initialise the states
  const [ data, setData, ] = useState([]);
  const [ form, setForm ] = useState({ id: '', name: '' });

  // I've attached one listener to the form element
  // (event delegation) which means that I need to check
  // that the event has come from the right element first,
  // and then I can update the form with
  // the name/value of the input
  function handleChange(e) {
    const { nodeName, name, value } = e.target;
    if (nodeName === 'INPUT') {
      setForm({...form, [name]: value })
    }
  }

  // Add the current form state to the dataset,
  // and reset the form
  function addEntry() {
    setData([ ...data, form ]);
    setForm({ id: '', name: '' });
  }

  // Only enable the button if both
  // fields are completed
  function isButtonDisabled() {
    return !form.id || !form.name;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onChange={handleChange}>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>ID</legend>
          <input name="id" type="text" value={form.id} />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Name</legend>
          <input name="name" type="text" value={form.name} />
        </fieldset>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={addEntry}
          disabled={isButtonDisabled()}
        >Add entry
        </button>
      </form>
      <Table data={data} />
    </div>
  );
};

function Table({ data }) {
  
  // Separate function to build the rows
  // from the array of objects
  function buildRows(data) {
    return data.map(obj => {
      return (
        <tr key={obj.id}>
          <td>{obj.id}</td>
          <td>{obj.name}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }
  
  // Don't show anything if the dataset is empty
  if (!data.length) return <div />;
  
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr className="heading">
          <td>ID</td>
          <td>Name</td>
        </tr>
        {buildRows(data)}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
button { margin-top: 1em; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 50%; display: block; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 1em; width: 75%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
td { padding: 0.3em; border: 1px solid #565656; }
.heading { font-weight: 700; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```